# how can I decode google's JWT response in python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I can decode it using this tool by google: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/jwtdecoder

This tells me that the encoding algorithm is `RS256`, which is not supported by the only python jwt library I've found: https://github.com/progrium/pyjwt

Anyone have an example of how to decode this?

Does the `google-python-api-client` have something that does this?

Thanks.

Comment: I've got a way to decode it, but still need a way to verify the signature. To decode, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922314/how-can-i-base64-encode-unicode-strings-in-javascript-and-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [oauth2client.client.verify_id_token()](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.client-module.html#verify_id_token).